# How to convert date int to date datetype using SQL at Athena

Tags: sql, pyspark, amazon-athena

My columns has values like '20200908', '20211012', '20220203' and I'm trying to convert this values to date format, like '2020-09-08', in AWS Athena. How could I do this convert?

I have been trying in so many ways, but it didnt work

CONVERT( date, AP.VQL100_CC_date_opened, 23 )

select cast(cast(40835 as datetime) as date)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DATE_PARSE()` function:

```sql
SELECT DATE_PARSE('20200908', '%Y%m%d');
```

Note that dates don't really have any internal "format" in a SQL database, but rather are usually just stored as binary.  If you really want to generate *text* then wrap the above with an extra call to `DATE_FORMAT()`:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_PARSE('20200908', '%Y%m%d'), '%Y-%m-%d');
```